# What short story features an explorer that finds a machine that allows him to simulate his death

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Trying to find a story about an explorer on some planet in space (possibly Mars), who comes across a machine that allows him to simulate and experience his death in many different ways, ultimately conquering his inherent fear of death as a human.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: What is the plot-buildup? Which language did you read this in? When did you read this? Do you remember when the short story was published?

Answer (score 6):

Could use more detail, but the story sounds vaguely like [Rogue Moon by Algis Budrys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_Moon) (1960), published at novel and novella lengths and adapted as a radio play. It's described here on Wikipedia:

> Dr. Edward Hawks runs a top-secret project for the U.S. Navy, using
> the facilities of Continental Electronics to investigate a large,
> deadly alien artifact found on the Moon. Volunteers enter and explore
> it, but are inevitably killed for violating the unknown alien rules in
> force within the structure. Hawks "must continue to send duplicates
> into the artifact, however, because each one moves a little closer to
> finding a way through the alien labyrinth" and, thus, closer to
> understanding what it is.
>
> Hawks has created a matter transmitter, one which scans a person or
> object to make a copy at the receivers on the Moon. The earthbound
> copy is placed in a state of sensory deprivation which allows him to
> share the experiences of the doppelgänger. However, none of the
> participants have been able to stay sane after experiencing death
> second hand.
>
> Barker is the first to retain his sanity, but even he is deeply
> affected the first time, exclaiming, "...it didn't care! I was nothing
> to it!" He returns again and again to the challenge, advancing a
> little further each time.

If not the story in question, it clearly sounds like an inspiration. (I see there are a number of other questions on the site for which Rogue Moon has been suggested as an answer, so this might wind up being marked as a duplicate.)